# Python directory structure for distutils

Tags: python, distutils

Being new to Python (but familar with a lot of other programming and scripting languages, like Tcl) i have created my first Python program, hosting it on Sourceforge using Subversion.

But as I usually do, and oblivious to Python conventions, I have put all my python files: module scripts and main script (not **init**.py) in a single directory, "trunk/pysrc". But looking into distutils and a bunch of howtos on how to distribute the program using distutils and PyPi, it appears that I'm supposed to have a specific structure with module scripts stored in subdirectorues.

My question is, is this a distutils **requirement**, or is it just a convention/recommended practice. Do I have to restructure my project to conform, or can I continue the way I have started.

Comment: Once you run setup.py much of the directory structure will be created for you.

Comment: maybe this is not quite important.

Comment: @Bob.Z Maybe it is.  Presumably the asker cares.  Do you think it's unimportant?  If so, why?

Comment: Well, I've found a lot of pages tha advocates various but similar directory structures, but there is no explanation on WHY it must be like that. I must understand why I must do it differently in Python than with other programming languages.